# Why don't fade out and fade in effects for music work in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, media-player, volume

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Summer
{
    public class AudioPlayer
    {
        public enum Repetition
        {
            ONCE,
            REPEAT
        }
        MediaPlayer MediaPlayer { get; } = new MediaPlayer();
        public string? SoundPath { get; set; }
        public double Volume { get; set; }
        public AudioPlayer() { }

        public void Play(Repetition repetition) 
        { 
            if(SoundPath != null) 
            {
                MediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(SoundPath, UriKind.Relative));
                MediaPlayer.MediaEnded -= RepeatSound;
                if(repetition == Repetition.REPEAT)
                    MediaPlayer.MediaEnded += RepeatSound;
                GraduallyPlay();
            }
        }
        void GraduallyPlay()
        {
            double currentVolume = 0.005;
            MediaPlayer.Volume = currentVolume;
            MediaPlayer.Play();
            MediaPlayer.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(async () =>
            {
                while ((currentVolume += 0.000005) <= Volume)
                {
                    MediaPlayer.Volume = currentVolume;
                    await Task.Delay(20);
                }
            });
        }

        void RepeatSound(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            MediaPlayer.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
            MediaPlayer.Play();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            MediaPlayer.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(async () =>
            {
                while (MediaPlayer.Volume >= 0)
                {
                    MediaPlayer.Volume -= 0.00005;
                    await Task.Delay(20);
                }
                MediaPlayer.Stop();
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Hello, I have the following class for playing my audio clips. I want my music volume to fade out when I stop playing. I am using Dispatcher class to achieve this, however it does not work for some reason, only `double currentVolume = 0.005;` line is executed when I use Play method. When I use Stop method, it does not stop the music. Why is this happening?

Comment: The Dispatcher is useless here. Simply make the complete method async and await the Task.Delay. Also 20ms seems to be too much. Using something like 200ms should produce the same effect but relief the UI thread.

Comment: Why aren't you using a doubleanimation on the volume?